# css bootstrap card header transparent not inherit parent background colour

Tags: css, transparency, background-color

Here's the situation, 
I have a background image for the whole page. The .container div has a white background color. I would like parts of the content (for instance a bootstrap card header) to be transparent and show the background image, therefore the card header not inheriting the container white background. Is this even possible ?

In the following example, I would like the .card-header element to be transparent thefore have the image as background.

```
<div style='background: url("img/bg.png");background-size: cover;'>
    <div class="container" style="background-color:white">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <span>header</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>Body</span>   
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful if you will provide code sandbox example.

Comment: You can't do that. It's not possible. You can't *ignore* a background like that.

Comment: That's what I thought.. Any trick to achieve this ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want the background appear through the white background of the panel, like a hole in a paper? Easiest solution would be to have a static background, which is not tied to the width of an element, then also apply the very same background to the card. Add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to give us something to get started on, mostly you just need to add some CSS.

Comment: Yes I could add the background image to the card but that's not the effect wanted as you said ot has to be a hole in a paper

Comment: I added a picture to show what I'm on about, the reddish/blueish background is the main background for the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Easiest solution would be to have a static background, which is not tied to the width of an element, then also apply the very same background to the card.

Example from my comment:

```css
body,
.bg {
  background: no-repeat url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature) fixed 100% 100%;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 50px;
}

.card-header,
.card-body {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:white">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header bg">
      <span>header</span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <span>Body</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes but no...as the header background has to match the full background, like a hole in a paper. Your solution means the background will be the same for all headers that's not the effect wanted.

Comment: @Arbiz my example does not show the whole background in the header. Just like a hole in a piece of paper. You can still play around with the background properties, that way the image wont be just static, but also move with your content. (As if you were to move the paper and the background together)

Comment: Yes this is is. Very clever and clean solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 
 <style>
  .left-slide-bar { width: 90px; height: 100vh; background-color: #C03; float: left;}
  .right-slide-content { width:calc(100% - 90px); padding-left:90px; position:relative;}
  
  .card { width:100%; position:relative; background-color:#fff;}
  .card-header { width:100%; position:relative; padding:30px 20px; background-color:#900;}
  .card-body { width:100%; position:relative;}
 </style>
 
  </head>
  <body>
    
 <div class="mainbody">
  <div class="left-slide-bar">
  
  
  </div>
  <div class="right-slide-content">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header">
        <span>header</span> 
       </div>
       <div class="card-body">
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet eleifend augue ac viverra. Maecenas lacinia laoreet massa, vel hendrerit risus. Phasellus et velit urna. Quisque nibh sapien, blandit sit amet nunc id, auctor ultricies ante. Nam vel nunc ut nisi varius semper. In sodales sapien elit, a facilisis quam ultrices ac. Phasellus elementum est diam, ut faucibus dolor dictum id. Aliquam elementum leo nec nunc feugiat, a molestie ante hendrerit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</span>   
       </div>  
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <script src="https://brm.io/js/libs/matchHeight/jquery.matchHeight.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
   $('.eq-height').matchHeight(options);
  });
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mm no...the card header has to show the document background image.

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can see this if you like.

```css
.card-header { background-color:transparent;}
.card-body { background-color:#ccc;}
```

```html
<div style='background-image: url("https://www.liberaldictionary.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/pattern.jpg"); background-size: cover;'>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <span>header</span> 
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquet eleifend augue ac viverra. Maecenas lacinia laoreet massa, vel hendrerit risus. Phasellus et velit urna. Quisque nibh sapien, blandit sit amet nunc id, auctor ultricies ante. Nam vel nunc ut nisi varius semper. In sodales sapien elit, a facilisis quam ultrices ac. Phasellus elementum est diam, ut faucibus dolor dictum id. Aliquam elementum leo nec nunc feugiat, a molestie ante hendrerit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</span>   
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes but the problem is that the container has to have a white background

Comment: ok can you show me the design of the website? that I will do easily

Comment: I added a picture to show what I'm on about, the reddish/blueish background is the main background for the page

Comment: I am processing HTML and CSS by reference your image.